# JAVA, play mp3 by URL

Tags: java, url, stream, mp3

I would like to create player that play mp3 music from the internet by url.
I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
import java.net.URL;
import sun.audio.AudioData;
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;
import sun.audio.ContinuousAudioDataStream;


public class Player {

  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

        URL url = new URL("http://stream10.jamendo.com/stream/247/mp31/07%20-%20Both%20-%20Je%20le%20veux%20aussi.mp3");
        AudioStream as = new AudioStream (url.openStream());
        AudioData data = as.getData();
        ContinuousAudioDataStream cas = new ContinuousAudioDataStream (data);
        AudioPlayer.player.start(cas);

  }

}
```

I got error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: could not create audio stream from input stream
        at sun.audio.AudioStream.<init>(AudioStream.java:65)
        at Player.main(Player.java:27)
Java Result: 1
```

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: You can download the URL to do a temp file and use it. 

ref: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html

Comment: I don't know how to fix your issue, but if you are interested in other libraries/APIs for doing audio in Java, I would recommend checking this out [JavaZoom](http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/mp3spi.html).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that for this specific library you have chosen, the Sun one, there is not support for mp3 and it comes down to exactly that.  As @Treebranch suggests, the better approach is to look at other APIs which could possibly handle mp3s.

From the JavaZoom page:

"MP3SPI is a Java Service Provider Interface that adds MP3 (MPEG 1/2/2.5 Layer 1/2/3) audio format support for Java Platform".